# How to split by a regex pattern and keep the delimitter on long string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string of addresses, with each address having a structure similar to:

```
123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432
```

I want to split the address string on the state, zipcode, house number (in the above instance this would be: OH 43071,432). While I have a regex combination that identifies these elements in each string (/\d+,\d+/), splitting based on this results in the delimiter being removed.

While I've seen other stack overflow threads that address similar questions to this one, none of those solutions work. For instance, if I place the regex combo in a capture group, like (/(\d+,\d+)/), it returns the zip code and address on another line:

```
[ '123 Main Street St. Louisville OH ',
  '43071,432',
```

Similarly, adding ?! or ?= in the regex combo is not effective.

How can I successfully split the address strings, so the output will mirror:

```
[ '123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432',
   Main Long Road St. Louisville OH 43071,786
```

The list of addresses I have is:

```
let addr =
  "123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432 Main Long Road St. Louisville OH 43071,786 High Street Pollocksville NY 56432,54 Holy Grail Street Niagara Town ZP 32908,3200 Main Rd. Bern AE 56210,1 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,10 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34342,10 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,58 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13000,22 Tokyo Av. Tedmondville SW 43098,674 Paris bd. Abbeville AA 45521,10 Surta Alley Goodtown GG 30654,45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32908,320 Main Al. Bern AE 56210,14 Gordon Park Atlanta RE 13000,100 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34342,2 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,5 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13000,2200 Tokyo Av. Tedmondville SW 43098,67 Paris St. Abbeville AA 45521,11 Surta Avenue Goodtown GG 30654,45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32918,320 Main Al. Bern AE 56215,14 Gordon Park Atlanta RE 13200,100 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34345,2 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13222,5 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13001,2200";
```

Comment: In general, this is an unbounded problem.  For example, streets can be called many different things, e.g. way, boulevard, avenue, highway, etc.  How can you write a regex to cover every possibility?

Comment: every address ends with a combo with state, zip, number 'OH 43071,432'. so it's definitely consistent.

Comment: _"How can I successfully split the address strings, so the output will mirror: `[ '123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432',
   432 Main Long Road St. Louisville OH 43071,786`"_ Why is `432` in the second match?

Comment: my mistake. i changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I successfully split the address strings, so the output will
>   mirror:
>
> ```
> [ '123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432',
>    Main Long Road St. Louisville OH 43071,786
> ```

To match the string at the updated question you can use `RegExp` `/[^\s][^,]+,\d+/g` and `String.prototype.match()` to match character that is not a space character `" "` followed by one or more characters that are not comma characters `,` followed by comma character and one or more digit characters

```js
let addr = "123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432 Main Long Road St. Louisville OH 43071,786 High Street Pollocksville NY 56432,54 Holy Grail Street Niagara Town ZP 32908,3200 Main Rd. Bern AE 56210,1 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,10 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34342,10 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,58 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13000,22 Tokyo Av. Tedmondville SW 43098,674 Paris bd. Abbeville AA 45521,10 Surta Alley Goodtown GG 30654,45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32908,320 Main Al. Bern AE 56210,14 Gordon Park Atlanta RE 13000,100 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34342,2 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,5 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13000,2200 Tokyo Av. Tedmondville SW 43098,67 Paris St. Abbeville AA 45521,11 Surta Avenue Goodtown GG 30654,45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32918,320 Main Al. Bern AE 56215,14 Gordon Park Atlanta RE 13200,100 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34345,2 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13222,5 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13001,2200";

let res = addr.match(/[^\s][^,]+,\d+/g);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

Comment: why does match work in that context? i thought match would just return the match '43071,432' but it returns the entire preceding string in your example. For instance, if i did res = addr.match(/\s/g); it would just return spaces.

Comment: @Dog Not sure what you mean by _"in that context"_. The `RegExp` matches one character that is not a space character followed by one or more characters that are not comma character followed by comma character followed by one or more digit characters.

Comment: yes but shouldn't that return '43071,432'? instead it returns '123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432'

Comment: for instance, it's matching '123 Main Street St. Louisville OH  ', even though that's not in the regex combo.

Comment: @Dog Why do you believe the `RegExp` should match only  '43071,432'? _"for instance, it's matching '123 Main Street St. Louisville OH ', even though that's not in the regex combo."_ Technically, that pattern is within the `RegExp` due to negated character class _"A negated or complemented character set. That is, it matches anything that is not enclosed in the brackets."_

Comment: because there are spaces in between each word in '123 Main Street St. Louisville OH' so i would think that would mean it would be in the match since no \s is included.

Comment: @Dog `\s` is included in the negated character class `[^,]+`. `[^\s]` is only included to avoid the first character of the match being a space character for all matches except the beginning of the string (the first match). Try the code without `[^\s]` to observe the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188163/discussion-between-dog-and-guest271314).

Comment: when i remove the [^\s], it adds a space in front of the matches. what i'm saying though is that your regex combo is specifically matching the end part '43071,432'. So i thought it would return all the end parts for each address. But instead, it is splitting on those and including the previous text. However, when i try to match things on my own like .match(/\s/) it returns the exact match, instead of everything preceding it like in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have overlapping matches, you won't be able to use `split` - instead, repeatedly use `.exec` with a capturing group, and extract the capturing group. Match a comma or the beginning of the string, then in a lookahead, capture the address string, followed by a comma and digits:

```js
const addr = "123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432 Main Long Road St. Louisville OH 43071,786 High Street Pollocksville NY 56432,54 Holy Grail Street Niagara Town ZP 32908,3200 Main Rd. Bern AE 56210,1 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,10 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34342,10 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,58 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13000,22 Tokyo Av. Tedmondville SW 43098,674 Paris bd. Abbeville AA 45521,10 Surta Alley Goodtown GG 30654,45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32908,320 Main Al. Bern AE 56210,14 Gordon Park Atlanta RE 13000,100 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34342,2 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,5 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13000,2200 Tokyo Av. Tedmondville SW 43098,67 Paris St. Abbeville AA 45521,11 Surta Avenue Goodtown GG 30654,45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32918,320 Main Al. Bern AE 56215,14 Gordon Park Atlanta RE 13200,100 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34345,2 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13222,5 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13001,2200";
let match;
const matches = [];
const pattern = /(?:^|,)(?=([^,]+,\d+))./g
while (match = pattern.exec(addr)) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need this operation only on the backend with last Node.js versions, you can use `split()` with a lookbehind assertion. This code can also be tested in the last Google Chrome versions.

```js
const addr = "123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071,432 Main Long Road St. Louisville OH 43071,786 High Street Pollocksville NY 56432,54 Holy Grail Street Niagara Town ZP 32908,3200 Main Rd. Bern AE 56210,1 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,10 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34342,10 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,58 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13000,22 Tokyo Av. Tedmondville SW 43098,674 Paris bd. Abbeville AA 45521,10 Surta Alley Goodtown GG 30654,45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32908,320 Main Al. Bern AE 56210,14 Gordon Park Atlanta RE 13000,100 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34342,2 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13000,5 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13000,2200 Tokyo Av. Tedmondville SW 43098,67 Paris St. Abbeville AA 45521,11 Surta Avenue Goodtown GG 30654,45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32918,320 Main Al. Bern AE 56215,14 Gordon Park Atlanta RE 13200,100 Pussy Cat Rd. Chicago EX 34345,2 Gordon St. Atlanta RE 13222,5 Gordon Road Atlanta RE 13001,2200";

console.log(addr.split(/(?<=\d+,\d+) /));
```